# How to get an Observable to return an array of transformed items (Rxjs)

Tags: angular, reactjs, rxjs, observable

I have an endpoint that produces a json list of products. I have a custom class type defined in my code for Products. I'm trying to get the data from the endpoint and have the json array of products transformed into an array of the Product class.

**Sample API json (simplified from my actual data):**

```
{
    "products": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Product 1",
        "materials": [{
            "id": 100,
            "desc": "wood"
        }, {
            "id": 101,
            "desc": "metal"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Product 2",
        "materials": [{
            "id": 100,
            "desc": "wood"
        }, {
            "id": 102,
            "desc": "brick"
        }]
    }]
}
```

**My code:**

```
loadProducts(){
    this.fetchProducts().subscribe(data => {
            console.log("the data:", data);
        })
}


fetchProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get("http://example.com/mydata.json")
        .map((response) => {
            const products = (response.json()).products;
            console.log("Converting to json" + products.length);
            return products;
        })
        .map( data => {
            console.log("Working on data: ", data);
            return new Product(data.id, data.name, data.materials);
        });
```

What I would expect to see in my console is..

```
"Converting to json 2"
"Working on data: " [object]
"Working on data: " [object]
"the data:" [object,object]
```

.. but what I am seeing is..

```
"Converting to json 2"
"Working on data: " [object,object]
"the data:" [object,object]
```

I thought that the .map function would run for each item sent to it. I can see that when I first call .map that it is being run once on the one item (the response) that it has -- and I know that there are products 2 items being returned. I would expect the second map function to then be run twice - once for each product item. Instead it seems that it's called once being passed in the array of products.

To make matters more complicated I want to also convert the list of materials into a Material class type I've created. I know I could do **all** of this with forEach loops, but I want to do this the "React" way.

Comment: You're thinking of `Array.map`, not `Observable.map`. You need to nest the former inside the latter. Using more explicit types on your callbacks may help clarify what's going on.

Comment: Yeah, I considered using Array.map inside my second Observable.map function. I guess I thought that React's Observable.map function worked the same way. What is the point of Obrservable.map if it doesn't get run on multiple items?

Comment: It *can* get run on multiple items; an observable is a *stream* of values, that callback is run for each one. In this case, each of those values is an array.

Comment: Gotcha. And I guess there's no simple way to split an array into a new stream?

Comment: @captain_jim1 see my answer

Comment: What do you mean by that? If you want to flatten out the stream, do something like `.flatMap((things: Thing[]) => Observable.from(things)).map((thing: Thing) => ...)`.

Comment: @JGFMK - the Product code is superfluous to this situation... the task I'm trying to accomplish is to simply get the JSON data (and array of data), and then perform a transformation on each item in that array .. in the "React" way.

The returns in the Observable methods are different than the returns for the function... there are essentially inline functions with their own returns going on there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally found the right combination of Observable operations to yield what I was looking for.

```
fetchProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get("http://examples.com/myData")
        .map((response) => {
            return response.json().products;
        })
        .switchMap( productArray => {
            return Observable.from(productArray);
        })
        .map( (productData: any) => {
            return new Product(
                productData.id,
                productData.name,
                productData.materials
            );
        })
        .toArray();
}
```

I misunderstood how Observable.map works -- thinking that it would be run on each item in my data when it actually runs on each piece of data.. and I had one piece of data coming to it -- an array. Thanks to @jonrsharpe for helping me there.

By using switchMap to return a new Observable from my array I was able to then emit each piece of data in my array separately. Thanks @giora-guttsait for that help.

Finally, I needed to combine all of those new pieces of the stream back onto a single array. Observable.toArray() did this for me.

Comment: @JGFMK - you gave me absolutely nothing new. You told me to use the Observable.map function and then covert the response to JSON -- literally everything you suggested I already was doing and had in my original question. That is why you got a -1 for your answer and why I didn't accept it

Comment: @GioraGuttsait - I did give you a +1 for your answer - someone else must have -1'd you. I have to wait one more day before I can accept my own answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Also @JGFMK - I DO need those returns because I've encapsulated the Observable function callbacks in curly braces--- .map( response => response.json()) is the same as .map( response => { return response.json();}) .. I use the encapsulation when I went to use debug statements -- which I was doing heavily during this issue.

Comment: Also man, I see that you end up doing a lot of `.map((bla: any) => { return something; })`, when you can make it shorter and cleaner by doing `.map((bla: any) => something)`, without the need of `{ return ... }`. It makes your code cleaner and more readable.

Comment: Absolutely -- I do that typically, but I was putting a lot of console logs into each .map to try and track the status of my data. I removed them when I submitted by Question/Answer, but got lazy and left the braces. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of doing `console.log`s in the `map`s, do them with the `do` operator. Doing so will allow your to seperate the logical commands from the debugging commands, while also allowing you to disable/enable the debug commands with the click of a `comment/uncomment`.

Comment: Well, I wanted console logs each step of the way through the Observable chain. With a .do() wouldn't I only be getting a snapshot at the point of the .do()?

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you're getting something like this:

```
this.http.get(...)
  .map(res => res.json().products)  // turns this into Observable<Products[]>
  .map(products => ... ) // here, products is already an array.
```

If you want to process this array same as you would in React, meaning doing something for each product, you could do something like:

```
this.http.get(...)
  .map(res => res.json().products)
  .switchMap(products => Observable.from(products))
```

Here, `Observable.from(products)` returns `Observable<Product>` and `switchMap` makes the chain return `Observable<Product>` you got before.

```
this.http.get(...)
  .map(res => res.json().products)
  .switchMap(products => Observable.from(products))
  .subscribe(product => console.log(product))
```

Will print every one of those products.

**Disclamer: I've not checked this code by running it, you may want a different operator then `switchMap`, but this is what I remember that works**

Comment: `.switchMap(products => Observable.of(products))` is basically a no-op, the resulting stream has the same type.

Comment: yup, figured it out. `Observable.from` should be used.

Comment: This wasn't exactly right, but it got me on the right path. I wanted an array of Products returned. This returned one Product twice. I could collect them into an array on my component's end, but I want that work contained in my service.

The chain I used to get things to work goes like this..
 return this.http.get("http://example.com/myData")
  .map((response) => {
    return response.json().products;
  })
  .switchMap( data => {
   return Observable.from(data);
  })
  .map( (product:any) => {
   return new Product( product.id, product.name, product.materials);
  })
  .toArray();